# Why does echo concatenate in CMake custom command

Tags: cmake, generated-code

I am messing around with build time source file generator, and I came across a strange behavior. If I have the following:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT
        ${GENERATED_FILE}
    COMMAND
        echo "// generated file" > ${GENERATED_FILE}
        echo "debugging echo"
    DEPENDS
        my_object_library
    VERBATIM
)
```

The generated file ends up with

```
// generated file echo debugging echo
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: I think you have to separate the `echo` commands with another `COMMAND` directive.

Comment: Agreed but I'd like to understand how this concatenation works.

Comment: On what OS are you seeing this behavior? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: "I'd like to understand how this concatenation works." - CMake simply passes every `COMMAND` argument to the shell. You may run in the command line `echo "// generated file" > <path-to-generated-file> echo "debugging echo"` and you will observe the same result.